# Windows hard links for directories

Tags: windows, hardlink

How can I make hard links for directories in Windows 7?
That means that the 2 (or more?) linked directories refer to the same inode (group of inodes) so they will be exact duplicated and every change to the one will also affect the other.
If I add a file (or change a file) in the one file that file will also be added/changed at the other directory because it's internally the same directory.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try Use `mklink /d /h linkname target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an interesting tool named [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) doing exactly this.

Comment: While I agree that may be a useful tool, it cannot make a hardlink to to a directory, if it is working on directories, then it is creating junction points.

Comment: @Zoredache Yep, exactly. It's using junctions.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a hardlink to a directory.  See the 'following are not' examples on this article about [Hard Links and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Mklink calls the [CreateHardLink function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363860(v=vs.85).aspx) and if you look at the description you see this summary.

> Establishes a hard link between an existing file and a new file. This
>   function is only supported on the NTFS file system, and **only for
>   files, not directories.**

You can create a junction (symlink), but hardlinks to directories are simply [not valid on most systems.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link#Limitations_of_hard_links).